# two functions not working in the same script, but working separately

Tags: python, function, xml-parsing, lxml

I am writing a script for parsing an html documents of this kind:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
     <p>
       <dfn>text</dfn>sometext<i>othertext</i></p>
     <p> .....................................</p>
     <p> .....................................</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried different packages for xml-parsing and stopped on lxml.
I need to iterate first on the contents of the `dfn` tags and then on the contents of the `i` tags, using regex. So, I wrote my 2 functions for each task. They work separately, but not not together in the same script. Here they are:

```
tree = etree.parse(html-file)

def f1():
   for x in tree.getiterator('dfn'):
       bu = x.text
       if re.findall(r'\s[A-Z]{1,2}$', bu):                  
           print(bu)

def f2():
    for x in tree.getiterator('i'):
       mu = x.text
       if re.findall(r'\W\s[A-Z]$', mu):
           print(mu)


def main():
    f1()
    f2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run the script, I get the correct output for **f1** followed by this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/elaine/Desktop/try2.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/elaine/Desktop/try2.py", line 33, in main
    f1()
  File "/home/elaine/Desktop/try2.py", line 20, in f1
    if re.findall(r'\s[A-Z]{1,2}$', bu):                  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: If you call `f2` first, does it give you the correct output followed by an error for `f1`?

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need to test if `x.text` is not `None`?

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at the stack trace, in particular this line:

```
File "/home/elaine/Desktop/try2.py", line 20, ***in f1***
```

This tells you that it is in your `f1` function that the error is occurring. If you comment out the call to `f2`, you should find that you still get that same error. It looks like `f1` is completing correctly because it gives you the correct output, but there must be something it encounters at the end that causes it to break.

I would suggest putting `print(bu)` right after the line `bu = x.text` to see what value `bu` is taking that is causing the regex to break. It might be that `bu` is `None`, though it is also possible that it is taking some other value.

If you would like more help, I would suggest posting the html file that you are trying to parse.